# Some Border Types in NSImageView Not Appearing

Tags: swift, xcode, nsimageview

I've looked in previous posts in SO and elsewhere for an answer but no luck. I'm putting images in an NSCollectionView as well as just a single image itself but the only border that seems to work is the grey Bezel border. Other types that are available don't show up, like Button or Groove. This is true no matter what scaling option I use, or even if I use it in code. I'm using NSImageView.imageFrameStyle.

I hope someone has some insight into this. I didn't provide any code since I didn't think that's necessary. Using Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2. Thanks for any help.

Comment: See [NSImageFrameStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimageview/framestyle) "Note that some of these constants are stylistically obsolete and should be considered deprecated.".

Comment: I saw that but I didn't really understand what it meant, since those styles are still in IB (and Swift), and grayBezel was still working. To me, saying some are "stylistically obsolete" is sort of a cop-out and doesn't really mean much if they are still there and Swift doesn't tell you which ones are considered obsolete. I even created another project with just a simple image view and the styles seem to work in that project, but Groove and Button lines are so small the effect isn't really noticeable. So yeah, from a certain point of view they aren't worth using.

Comment: The documentation tells you which ones are deprecated.

Comment: Perhaps you could point out which ones in the link you provided. Not seeing it there,

Comment: See the documentation of `none`, `photo`, `grayBezel`, `groove` and `button`.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you.